# Possible to build support for a filesystem directly into an application?

Tags: c, linux, macos, filesystems

I am wondering if it's possible to write an application that will access a foreign filesystem, but without needing support for that filesystem from the operating system. For example, I'd like to write an app in C that runs on Mac OS X that can browse / copy files from an ext2/ext3 formatted disk. Of course, you'd have to do all the transfers through the application (not through the system using cp or the Finder), but that would be OK for my purpose. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are user space libraries that allow you to access file systems.

The Linux-NTFS library (libntfs) allows you to access NTFS file systems and there are user space programs like `ntfsfix` to do things to the file system.

[E2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) does the same for ext2, ext3 and ext4 filesystems.

As Basile mentioned, Mtools is another one that provides access to FAT partitions.

There was even a program that does exactly what you're looking for on Windows. It's called [ext2explore](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/ext2explore.shtml) and allows you to access ext2 partitions from Windows.

Comment: The asker target is Mac OS X, not windows.

Comment: I know which is why I mentioned that it was *on Windows*. The application does something similar to what he's looking for which is an application that directly accesses a file system. It's a proof of concept (albeit on a different OS).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. For example the GNU [mtools](http://www.gnu.org/s/mtools/) utility are doing that (assuming a way to access the raw device or partition) for MS-DOS FAT file systems.

However, file systems inside the kernel are usually very well tested and optimized.

Comment: The "assuming a way to access the raw device" must not be minimized :-) No modern operating system authorizes some random processes to access "raw things".

Comment: Via `/dev`? You'll be able to access the file systems raw then wouldn't you?

Comment: So would I start by reading raw data from the disk by doing something like fopen("/dev/sda1","rb") and then working with the data based on the filesystem specs?

Comment: Yes, or you could use `mmap` (or the `read(2)` syscall). However, be careful: your first bugs will probably corrupt the filesystem, so make backups before experimentation. I think that there is a libext2 library to help you. I used it a dozen years ago to make an experimental Ext2 file system for the VSTa microkernel.

Comment: No Synthetix. Create a file using `dd if=/dev/zero of=something.ext3` (provide a size too). Then format it into an ext3 file system using `mkfs.ext3 -F`. Now, you have a "disk image" which you can mount using a loopback device. Even if you corrupt it, there are no problems since it's "yours". You can run your experimental programs on this file rather than on a live partition.

Comment: Thanks, Noufal. Great idea on the disk image. Why didn't I think of that? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. For a regular user Application is usually not possible because access to block devices is restricted to root only. Every block device should give read/write to the needed block device for that effect. This would need at best a server/client approach where a service is started on the machine and configured to give the permissions on a per block device manner.

The somewhat easier alternative would be you to use the MacFUSE implementation.

Look here: 
http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/ 
http://groups.google.com/group/macfuse?pli=1

The MacFuse project seems no longer mantained, but can give you a starting point for your project.

The dirty and quick approach is the following as root `chmod 666 /dev/diskN`

Answer (score 0):

You can hijack syscalls and library calls from your application and then redirect reads/writes to anything like a KV store or a distributed DB layer (using the regular calls for the "virtual devices" that you do not support).

Then, the possibilities are boundless because you don't have to reach the physical/virtual devices when someone asks for them (resolving privilege issues).